# Modal popup appears behind modal background in Ajax Control Toolkit

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modal-dialog

[image]**Problem:**

Under IE8 the popup panel for the Ajax Control Toolkit is falling underneath the modalBackground (see screen shot). This only happens in IE8.

**Previous Attempts:**

I tried overriding the z-index (it looks like a z-index issue) in the css file as such:

```
.modalPopup
{
    background-color: white;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    z-index:100000001 !important; 
}
```

and the issue still exists. Using firebug in Firefox I can check the change in the z-index when the user clicks on the button to display the modal popup, and the z-index changes correctly.

**Code:**

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPsdE" runat="server" Enabled="true" DynamicServicePath=""
    OkControlID="OkButton" 
    CancelControlID="CancelButton"
    TargetControlID="MoreServers"
    PopupControlID="ModalPanel"
    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>




<asp:Panel ID="ModalPanel" runat="server" >
  <div class="modalPopup" >
    test <asp:Button ID="OkButton" runat="server" Text="Okay"/>
    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel"/>
  </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

CSS:

```
.modalBackground 
{
    position:fixed; 
    background-color:#000; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
    opacity:0.5;  
}
.modalPopup
{
    background-color: white;
    width:200px;
    height:150px;
    z-index:100000001 !important; 
}
```

I've also tried setting the z-index of the modalBackground lower, with no success.

**Questions:**

1. Has anybody ever had this issue before? If so could you point me in the right direction?
2. If you haven't had this issue, what would be some things you would look at? I'm completely out of ideas

Comment: You could download the code for the AjaxToolKit and find where the z-index is set for the ModalPopupExtender and increase the value.  And then compile your own dll and use it.  I have had to do this when I could not override the embedded resource's styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turns out not to be in anything that I posted. The issue is in our template somewhere, maybe a tag not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the attribute

position:fixed; to position:absolute;

Comment: I just checked that out, appreciate the attempt but it didn't solve the issue :(

Comment: Just a try. Try setting display:inline;

Answer (score -1):

Set the Panel background color (`BackColor="White"`); it will resolve your problem.